# Email Test Case Log to Tester

Tags: selenium-ide

I am using selenium-ide and my question is as follows.  How can I email the log results from a Test Case to my email address?

I have searched numerous sites on the web including Stack Overflow and have not found a solution.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you wanting this to happen automatically at the end of a test? Or are you just trying to find a way to have the log stored externally for you to then email over?

If it's the latter then this can be achieved with the file logging plugin for Selenium IDE (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/file-logging-selenium-ide/)

If you're looking for this to be done automatically then it may not be possible, as selenium IDE can only interact with firefox so may have trouble attaching files from within the explorer pane.

Comment: I would like to email the log results from a Test Case to my email address when the test case has completed.